# Using json_encode for URL using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I need to retrieve URL's which are coming from a PHP file which include mysql variables. Unfortunately they are not being returned correctly.

Below is the html file I am linking to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="index" href="toc1.php" type="application/json">
</head>
```

My toc1.php was file:

```
<?php
  $username = $_GET['username'];
  $papername = $_GET['papername'];

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $username = json_encode($username);
  $papername = json_encode($papername);
?>

[{
"url": <?php echo '<a href="http://www.yoozpaper.com/cover.php?
username=' . $username . '&papername=' . $papername . '" ></a>';?>
},
{
"url": <?php echo '<a href="http://www.yoozpaper.com/tocindex.php?
username=' . $username . '&papername=' . $papername . '" ></a>';?>
},]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just removing the json_encode??

The json_encode function makes json object form array:

```
$json = array();
$json['something'] = "something else";
$json['and_again'] = "more things";
```

And then `json_encode($json)` returns:

```
{
     "something": "something",
     "and_again": "things"
}
```

So json encode a string:

```
$username = "John Doe";
echo json_encode($username);
```

Will result in something as `"John Doe"` or an error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following:

```
$list = array();

$objItem = new stdClass();
$objItem->url = '<a href="…?username=' . $username . '&papername=' . $papername . '"></a>';
$list[] = $objItem;

// add more items
```

And finally, output that:

```
echo json_encode($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` call must be the very first line of the file, see [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). So change it to

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$username = $_GET['username'];
$papername = $_GET['papername'];

$username = json_encode($username);
$papername = json_encode($papername);
?>
```

And from where the `GET` variables are supposed to come? You probably want to change the link to

```
<link rel="index" href="toc1.php?username=foo&papername=bar" type="application/json">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json `{"some":"some"}`

here href=''

```
<a href='{"some":"some"}'>Some</a>
```

not this

```
<a href="{"some":"some"}">Some</a>
```